# Go, trying to loop date Regex results

Tags: regex, go

Doing a FindAllStringSubmatch regex match including named groups for different date formats. I am having trouble looping results. The commented out conditional makes it work, but not cleanly and it breaks as I add additional matches. I feel like I am approaching it wrong and would like some redirection. thx/

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    text := "12/31/1956 31/11/1960"
    reg := []string{`(?P<month>1[12])/(?P<day>\d\d)/(?P<year>19\d\d)`, `(?P<day>\d\d)/(?P<month>1[12])/(?P<year>19\d\d)`}
    // Combine them, case ignored
    regall := "(?i)" + strings.Join(reg, "|")
    myExp := regexp.MustCompile(regall)
    match := myExp.FindAllStringSubmatch(text, -1)
    fmt.Println("Match", match, len(match))
    fmt.Println("Names", myExp.SubexpNames(), len(myExp.SubexpNames()))
    for i := 0; i < len(match); i++ {
        result := make(map[string]string)
        for j, name := range myExp.SubexpNames() {
            result[name] = match[i][j]
            //if (result["month"] != "" && result["day"] != "" && result["year"] != "") {
                fmt.Println(match[i][0],i,j,result["month"] + "/" + result["day"] + "/" + result["year"])
            //}
        }
    }
}

Results in:
Match [[12/31/1956 12 31 1956   ] [31/11/1960    31 11 1960]] 2
Names [ month day year day month year] 7
12/31/1956 0 0 //
12/31/1956 0 1 12//
12/31/1956 0 2 12/31/
12/31/1956 0 3 12/31/1956
12/31/1956 0 4 12//1956
12/31/1956 0 5 //1956
12/31/1956 0 6 //
31/11/1960 1 0 //
31/11/1960 1 1 //
31/11/1960 1 2 //
31/11/1960 1 3 //
31/11/1960 1 4 /31/
31/11/1960 1 5 11/31/
31/11/1960 1 6 11/31/1960
```

Answer (score 0):

After some rethinking and help from above, with aid of the above answer I came up looping the regex's separately to better handle overlapping named capture groups I came up with this: (posted for benefit of others and any critique is welcome)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    month_d := `(?P<month>1[012]|0?[1-9])`
    month_t := `(?P<month>jan(?:uary|.)?|feb(?:ruary|.)?|mar(?:ch|.)?|apr(?:il|.)?|may(.)|jun(?:e|.)?|jul(?:y|.)?|aug(?:ust|.)?|sep(?:tember|t|t.|.)?|oct(?:ober|.)?|nov(?:ember|.)?|dec(?:ember|.)?)`
    day := `(?P<day>3[01]|[12][0-9]|[0]?[1-9])(?:\s)?(?:th|rd|nd|st)?`
    year := `(?P<year>(?:19|20)?\d\d)`
    sep_d := `[?:/.-]`
    sep_t := `[?:,\s]`

    text := "fedskjnkvdsj February 6 2004 sdffd Jan 12th 56 1/12/2000 2013/12/1 2099/12/5 1/12/1999 dsfjhfdhj"
    regs := []string{
        "(" + month_d + sep_d + day + sep_d + year + ")",
        "(" + year + sep_d + month_d + sep_d + day + ")",
        "(" + day + sep_d + month_d + sep_d + year + ")",
        "(" + month_t + sep_t + day + sep_t + year + ")",
        "(" + day + sep_t + month_t + sep_t + year + ")",
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(regs); i++ {
        myExp, err := regexp.Compile("(?i)" + regs[i])
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("There is a problem with your regexp.\n")
            return
        }
        match := myExp.FindAllStringSubmatch(text, -1)
        //fmt.Println("Match", match, len(match))
        //fmt.Println("Names", myExp.SubexpNames(), len(myExp.SubexpNames()))
        for j := 0; j < len(match); j++ {
            result := make(map[string]string)
            for k, name := range myExp.SubexpNames() {
                result[name] = match[j][k]
            }
            // Fix Month
            themonth := strings.ToLower(result["month"])

            if len(themonth) == 1 {
                themonth = "0" + themonth
            }
            if len(themonth) >= 3 {
                themonth = themonth[0:3]
                switch themonth {
                case "jan":
                    themonth = "01"
                case "feb":
                    themonth = "02"
                case "mar":
                    themonth = "03"
                case "apr":
                    themonth = "04"
                case "may":
                    themonth = "05"
                case "jun":
                    themonth = "06"
                case "jul":
                    themonth = "07"
                case "aug":
                    themonth = "08"
                case "sep":
                    themonth = "09"
                case "oct":
                    themonth = "10"
                case "nov":
                    themonth = "11"
                case "dec":
                    themonth = "12"
                default:
                    fmt.Println("Month Error: " + themonth)
                    os.Exit(2)
                }
            }
            // Day
            theday := result["day"]
            if len(theday) == 1 {
                theday = "0" + theday
            }
            // Fix Year
            theyear := result["year"]
            if len(theyear) == 2 {
                val_year, err := strconv.ParseInt(theyear,10,0)
                if err != nil {
                    // handle error
                    fmt.Println(err)
                    os.Exit(2)
                }
                if val_year > 50 {
                    theyear = "19" + theyear
                } else {
                    theyear = "20" + theyear
                }
            }
            date := themonth + "/" + theday + "/" + theyear
            fmt.Println(date)
        }
    }
}
```